# How to share components between mobile and web without a symbolic link?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-web

**Preferable one:**

```
components/
platforms/
  web/
    index.tsx
  mobile/
    index.tsx
```

This one works on mobile but throws `Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined` on web.

**Working one:**

```
web/
  index.tsx
  shared/ *
    components
mobile/
  index.tsx
  shared/ *
    components/

* : symbolic link
```

This one works both on mobile and web but uses symbolic link.

Comment: Resources: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TKvL2dasRrE